# How can I override java -Xmx option in application?

Tags: java, overriding

I am running a script in PowerShell, that calls a java application, but this application fails due to Out.of.memory.error: Heap Size. I created environment variable, but it didn't work. From the dump txt file I found out, that the java_command_line contains `-Xmx512m` option:

`IBM_JAVA_COMMAND_LINE=C:\Program Files\ (x86)\IBM\Java70\jre\bin\java.exe -Xmx512m -classpath C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop\Nessus_Scripts\nessusconverter.exe;...`

From what I learned, this overrides my created environment variable and lowers the max heap size for this application. I guess it is coded in the called application. My problem is, that I don't know the author of the application and need it for my work. I am also time-limited, so some deep debugging or improving of this app is off limits.

Is there a way to override the option set in the application (without interfering in the app)?

I have Windows 7 and IBM SDK Java version 7.0.

Script calling the java app:

```
Function CallNessusConverter ( [Array]$input_files
[String]$output_filename, [String]$exceptions_filename, 
[String]$hosts_filename, [String]$output_directory ) {    

[String]$output_XML_file = $output_directory + "\" +  $output_filename + ".xml"
[String]$output_Issue_file = $output_directory + "\" +  $output_filename + "-Issues.csv"
[String]$output_Missed_file = $output_directory + "\" +  $output_filename + "-NotScanned.csv"
[String]$input_XML_files = ""

foreach ($file in $input_files){
$input_XML_files += " " + $file    
}

Write-Host "**** Calling nessusconverter ****"

[string]$CLI_nessusconverter = ".\nessusconverter -inputXMLfiles $input_files -exceptions $exceptions_filename -hosts $hosts_filename  -outputXML $output_XML_file -outputIssue $output_Issue_file -rmunknown -outputMissed $output_Missed_file"

iex $CLI_nessusconverter 

...

CallNessusConverter $input_files $output_filename $exceptions_filename $hosts_filename $output_directory`
```

Comment: Can you post the line in the script that invokes the `java` command? The answer will differ based on if your script references that environment variable directly or java is set up to check that variable for default options.

Comment: I added the script, so you can see, that the java command is not in there, it is invoked by the application itself, and that is hard to change for me. My guess is that the variable is set up directly, it is the same on different versions of java, the first one I run it on had 256m default options.

Comment: Well, I have no idea what nessusconverter is or how it runs, though I suspect it invokes java and unless their documentation provides some way for you to change java parameters, you're going to be out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

As some kind of workaround, if there no other solution, you could try to replace the java.exe with a file that calls the real java with the desired parameters... Of course this is not a good idea if other applications use this java.exe as well.